Fix button to bottom of sidebar while also overlapping nav items at small viewports
tl;dr I want to make the log out button stick to the bottom of the nav at all times.
Intro
I'm working on a sidebar navigation for a user dashboard. My vision is for the sidebar to span from the top to the bottom of the viewport, no matter the screen size. With this, it's important that the nav is scrollable, when the nav items overflow. In this, I always want the log out button visible, and fixed to the bottom of the nav container. This means, when nav items overflow, the log out button will appear on top of those items.
Issue
Although using position: sticky; bottom: 0; does achieve the desired effect of keeping the log out button always visible on smaller viewport heights, it does not allow the log out button to stick to the bottom of the nav at larger viewport heights.
Goal
With Screenshots
I would like both screenshots to work with the same CSS.
Smaller Viewports – Uses position: sticky; bottom: 0;
This works better than position: absolute on smaller viewports due to its ability to stay at the bottom of the container when you scroll. The downside is, it doesn't stay at the bottom of the container on larger viewports.

Larger Viewports – Uses position: absolute; bottom: 0.5rem;
This works better than position: sticky on larger viewports due to its ability to always stay at the bottom of the container, even when the container stretches. The downside is, it doesn't stay at the bottom when you scroll within the container on a smaller viewport.

Code
Please review the CodePen. The code below is incomplete condensed and incomplete, because it was too many characters for StackOverflow. The demo still works though.
I intentionally added the class log-out-button-container in CodePen. You can find it at the bottom of the CSS in the debug section. This should be the only class you need to edit to get it to work, I think.


/* BEGIN TAILWIND RESET */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
}
::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: "";
}
html,
:host {
  line-height: 1.5;
  tab-size: 4;
  font-family: -apple-system, "Helvetica Neue", BlinkMacSystemFont, Arial,
    Helvetica, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji,
    Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol, Noto Color Emoji;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  font-variation-settings: normal;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
}
hr {
  height: 0;
  color: inherit;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
button {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-feature-settings: inherit;
  font-variation-settings: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
h1,
hr {
  margin: 0;
}
ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* END TAILWIND RESET */
/* BEGIN BOILERPLATE */
:root {
  --brand-primary-50: 356 100% 97%;
  --brand-primary-100: 357 100% 90%;
  --brand-primary-200: 359 100% 68%;
  --brand-primary-300: 358 98% 64%;
  --brand-primary-400: 358 75% 60%;
  --brand-primary-500: 358 68% 57%;
  --brand-primary-600: 358 55% 50%;
  --brand-primary-700: 358 64% 37%;
  --brand-primary-800: 358 47% 34%;
  --brand-primary-900: 358 51% 17%;
  --brand-primary-950: 358 60% 12%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
html {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}
body {
  min-height: 100svh;
  background-color: rgb(250 250 250);
}
h1 {
  text-wrap: balance;
  color: rgb(7 7 7);
  hanging-punctuation: first last;
}
button,
a {
  text-wrap: pretty;
}
svg {
  fill: rgb(7 7 7);
  fill: inherit;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0);
  }
  h1 {
    color: rgb(250 250 250);
  }
  svg {
    fill: rgb(250 250 250);
    fill: inherit;
  }
  @media (pointer: fine) {
    body {
      background-color: rgb(10 10 10);
    }
  }
}
/* END BOILERPLATE */
/* BEGIN PAGE STYLES */
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}
.-right-px {
  right: -1px;
}
.bottom-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.z-10 {
  z-index: 10;
}
.size-8 {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}
.h-dvh {
  height: 100dvh;
}
.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
.min-h-fit {
  min-height: fit-content;
}
.w-0 {
  width: 0;
}
.min-w-fit {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.contents {
  display: contents;
}
.overflow-visible {
  overflow: visible;
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.overflow-x-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.m-2 {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
.mlx-auto {
  margin-inline: auto;
}
.mly-auto {
  margin-block: auto;
}
.rounded-lg {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.rounded-xl {
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}
.rounded-full {
  border-radius: 9999px;
}
.bg-white {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: hsl(0 0% 100% / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.bg-primary-50 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.text-lg {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
.whitespace-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.font-semibold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.font-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.leading-none {
  line-height: 1;
}
.text-neutral-700 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(64 64 64 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-primary-400 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-primary-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-500) / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}
.border-neutral-500\/25 {
  border-color: rgb(115 115 115 / 0.25);
}
.fill-current {
  fill: currentColor;
}
.fill-primary-400 {
  fill: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / 1);
}
.grid-cols-0 {
  grid-template-columns: 0fr;
}
.grid-cols-1 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.grid-cols-\[2rem_1fr\] {
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
}
.col-start-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.col-end-2 {
  grid-column-end: 2;
}
.row-start-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.row-end-2 {
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.grid-flow-col {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.place-items-center {
  place-items: center;
}
.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.p-px {
  padding: 1px;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.p-4 {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.pr-1 {
  padding-right: 0.25rem;
}
.pb-12 {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.-translate-x-8 {
  --tw-translate-x: -2rem;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.translate-y-12 {
  --tw-translate-y: 3rem;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.translate-y-\[6\%\] {
  --tw-translate-y: 6%;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.shadow-xl {
  --tw-shadow: 0 20px 25px -5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1),
    0 8px 10px -6px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 20px 25px -5px var(--tw-shadow-color),
    0 8px 10px -6px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000),
    var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}
.ring-0 {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0
    var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0
    calc(0px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow),
    var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}
.ring-primary-400\/50 {
  --tw-ring-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / 0.5);
}
.ring-offset-0 {
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
}
.ring-offset-neutral-50 {
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fafafa;
}
.transition-fill {
  transition-property: fill;
}
.transition-\[background-color\] {
  transition-property: background-color;
}
.transition-\[padding-right\] {
  transition-property: padding-right;
}
.transition-\[grid-template-columns\] {
  transition-property: grid-template-columns;
}
.transition-\[padding-right\2c padding-bottom\] {
  transition-property: padding-right, padding-bottom;
}
.transition-\[transform\2c background-color\2c box-shadow\] {
  transition-property: transform, background-color, box-shadow;
}
.transition-\[transform\2c grid-template-columns\2c grid-template-rows\] {
  transition-property: transform, grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows;
}
.transition-\[grid-template-columns\2c margin-left\2c padding-right\] {
  transition-property: grid-template-columns, margin-left, padding-right;
}
.transition-\[transform\2c background-color\2c color\2c box-shadow\] {
  transition-property: transform, background-color, color, box-shadow;
}
.duration-300 {
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
.duration-500 {
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.ease-exponential {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0, 0.99);
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
.active\:bg-primary-100:active {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-100) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.active\:bg-primary-400:active {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.active\:text-primary-50:active {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50) / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.focus-visible\:scale-101:focus-visible {
  --tw-scale-x: 1.01;
  --tw-scale-y: 1.01;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.focus-visible\:outline-none:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
.focus-visible\:ring:focus-visible {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0
    var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0
    calc(3px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow),
    var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}
.focus-visible\:ring-offset-2:focus-visible {
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 2px;
}
.active\:scale-99:active {
  --tw-scale-x: 0.99;
  --tw-scale-y: 0.99;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.data-\[current-route\]\:pointer-events-none[data-current-route] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
:where([data-current-route])
  .\[\:where\(\[data-current-route\]\)_\&\]\:bg-primary-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
:where([data-current-route])
  .\[\:where\(\[data-current-route\]\)_\&\]\:text-primary-400 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
:where([data-current-route])
  .\[\:where\(\[data-current-route\]\)_\&\]\:fill-primary-50 {
  fill: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50));
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:w-8 {
  width: 2rem;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:ml-4 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:grid-cols-1 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:pr-2 {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:pr-3 {
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:pb-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:translate-x-0 {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:translate-y-0 {
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
:where([data-expanded]) .\[\:where\(\[data-expanded\]\)_\&\]\:rotate-180 {
  --tw-rotate: 180deg;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
    skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
    scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
}
.before\:absolute::before {
  content: var(--tw-content, "");
  position: absolute;
}
.before\:inset-x-0::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.before\:-bottom-2::before {
  bottom: -0.5rem;
}
.before\:top-0::before {
  top: 0;
}
.before\:rounded-2xl::before {
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.before\:bg-white\/90::before {
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.9);
}
.before\:backdrop-blur-sm::before {
  --tw-backdrop-blur: blur(4px);
  backdrop-filter: var(--tw-backdrop-blur, 0) var(--tw-backdrop-brightness, 1)
    var(--tw-backdrop-contrast, 1) var(--tw-backdrop-grayscale, 0)
    var(--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate, 0) var(--tw-backdrop-invert, 0)
    var(--tw-backdrop-opacity, 1) var(--tw-backdrop-saturate, 1)
    var(--tw-backdrop-sepia, 0);
}
@media (pointer: fine) {
  .desktop\:hover\:bg-primary-50\/50:hover {
    background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50) / 0.5);
  }
  .desktop\:hover\:bg-primary-400:hover {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-400) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
  .desktop\:hover\:text-primary-50:hover {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50) / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
  .desktop\:hover\:scale-101:hover {
    --tw-scale-x: 1.01;
    --tw-scale-y: 1.01;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
      rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
      skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
      scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
  }
  .group\/nav-item:hover .desktop\:group-hover\/nav-item\:text-neutral-900 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(23 23 23 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
  .group\/nav-item:hover .desktop\:group-hover\/nav-item\:scale-105 {
    --tw-scale-x: 1.05;
    --tw-scale-y: 1.05;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
      rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
      skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
      scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
  }
  .group\/nav-item:hover .desktop\:group-hover\/nav-item\:shadow-md {
    --tw-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1),
      0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
    --tw-shadow-colored: 0 4px 6px -1px var(--tw-shadow-color),
      0 2px 4px -2px var(--tw-shadow-color);
    box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000),
      var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
  }
  .group\/nav-item:hover
    .desktop\:group-hover\/nav-item\:shadow-primary-600\/15 {
    --tw-shadow-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-600) / 0.15);
    --tw-shadow: var(--tw-shadow-colored);
  }
  .desktop\:active\:bg-primary-100:active {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-100) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
  .desktop\:active\:bg-primary-500:active {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-500) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
  .desktop\:active\:scale-99:active {
    --tw-scale-x: 0.99;
    --tw-scale-y: 0.99;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x, 0), var(--tw-translate-y, 0))
      rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x, 0))
      skewY(var(--tw-skew-y, 0)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x, 1))
      scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y, 1));
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .dark\:bg-neutral-800 {
    background-color: rgb(38 38 38);
  }
  .dark\:text-neutral-300 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(212 212 212 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
  .dark\:ring-offset-neutral-950 {
    --tw-ring-offset-color: #0a0a0a;
  }
  @media (pointer: fine) {
    .dark\:desktop\:hover\:bg-primary-50\/25:hover {
      background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-50) / 0.25);
    }
    .group\/nav-item:hover
      .dark\:desktop\:group-hover\/nav-item\:text-neutral-100 {
      --tw-text-opacity: 1;
      color: rgb(245 245 245 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    }
    .dark\:desktop\:active\:bg-primary-200\/25:active {
      background-color: hsl(var(--brand-primary-200) / 0.25);
    }
  }
}
/* END PAGE STYLES */
<body><aside aria-expanded="true" class="h-dvh p-4 float-left" data-expanded="true"><nav class="h-full overflow-y-scroll rounded-xl bg-white p-2 shadow-xl dark:bg-neutral-800" aria-label="side-nav"><div class="z-10 grid p-2 grid-flow-col"><a class="flex items-center text-primary-500 pb-12 transition-[padding-right,padding-bottom] duration-300 ease-exponential [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pb-0 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pr-3" target="_self" rel="prefetch" href="#"><div class="grid flex-shrink-0 transition-[transform,grid-template-columns,grid-template-rows] duration-500 ease-exponential"><div id='logo-icon-container' class="overflow-hidden transition-[padding-right] duration-500 ease-exponential pr-1"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="size-8 fill-current p-px"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg></div></div><div id='logo-text-container' class="grid flex-shrink-0 transition-[grid-template-columns] duration-500 ease-exponential grid-cols-1"><span class="block translate-y-[6%] overflow-x-hidden text-lg uppercase leading-none">Andrilla</span></div></a><div class="w-0 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:w-8"><button class="min-w-fit font-semibold ring-0 ring-primary-400/50 ring-offset-0 ring-offset-neutral-50 duration-300 ease-exponential focus-visible:scale-101 focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 active:scale-99 desktop:hover:scale-101 desktop:active:scale-99 dark:ring-offset-neutral-950 bg-primary-50 text-primary-400 transition-[transform,background-color,color,box-shadow] active:bg-primary-400 active:text-primary-50 desktop:hover:bg-primary-400 desktop:hover:text-primary-50 desktop:active:bg-primary-500 absolute size-8 -translate-x-8 translate-y-12 rounded-lg p-2 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:translate-x-0 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:translate-y-0 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:rotate-180" aria-controls="side-nav" type="button"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="-right-px h-full overflow-visible fill-current mlx-auto"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg><span class="sr-only">Collapse Side Nav</span></button></div></div><hr class="rounded-full border border-neutral-500/25 m-2"><menu class="contents"><li class="group/nav-item rounded-xl transition-[background-color] duration-500 ease-exponential active:bg-primary-100 data-[current-route]:pointer-events-none desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/50 desktop:active:bg-primary-100 dark:desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/25 dark:desktop:active:bg-primary-200/25" data-current-route="true"><a class="grid grid-cols-[2rem_1fr] p-2" target="_self" rel="prefetch" href="#"><div class="grid size-8 place-items-center rounded-lg bg-primary-50 p-2 transition-[transform,background-color,box-shadow] duration-500 ease-exponential desktop:group-hover/nav-item:scale-105 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-md desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-primary-600/15 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:bg-primary-400"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 row-end-2 overflow-visible fill-primary-400/0 transition-fill duration-500 ease-exponential [:where([data-current-route])_&]:fill-primary-50"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg></div><div class="grid grid-cols-0 transition-[grid-template-columns,margin-left,padding-right] duration-500 ease-exponential mly-auto [:where([data-expanded])_&]:ml-4 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:grid-cols-1 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pr-2"><span class="overflow-x-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-bold uppercase leading-none text-neutral-700 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-300 dark:desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-100 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:text-primary-400">Dashboard</span></div></a></li><li class="group/nav-item rounded-xl transition-[background-color] duration-500 ease-exponential active:bg-primary-100 data-[current-route]:pointer-events-none desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/50 desktop:active:bg-primary-100 dark:desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/25 dark:desktop:active:bg-primary-200/25"><a class="grid grid-cols-[2rem_1fr] p-2" target="_self" rel="prefetch" href="#"><div class="grid size-8 place-items-center rounded-lg bg-primary-50 p-2 transition-[transform,background-color,box-shadow] duration-500 ease-exponential desktop:group-hover/nav-item:scale-105 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-md desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-primary-600/15 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:bg-primary-400"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 row-end-2 overflow-visible fill-primary-400 transition-fill duration-500 ease-exponential [:where([data-current-route])_&]:fill-primary-50/0"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg></div><div class="grid grid-cols-0 transition-[grid-template-columns,margin-left,padding-right] duration-500 ease-exponential mly-auto [:where([data-expanded])_&]:ml-4 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:grid-cols-1 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pr-2"><span class="overflow-x-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-bold uppercase leading-none text-neutral-700 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-300 dark:desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-100 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:text-primary-400">Forms</span></div></a></li><hr class="rounded-full border border-neutral-500/25 m-2"><li class="group/nav-item rounded-xl transition-[background-color] duration-500 ease-exponential active:bg-primary-100 data-[current-route]:pointer-events-none desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/50 desktop:active:bg-primary-100 dark:desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/25 dark:desktop:active:bg-primary-200/25"><a class="grid grid-cols-[2rem_1fr] p-2" target="_self" rel="prefetch" href="#"><div class="grid size-8 place-items-center rounded-lg bg-primary-50 p-2 transition-[transform,background-color,box-shadow] duration-500 ease-exponential desktop:group-hover/nav-item:scale-105 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-md desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-primary-600/15 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:bg-primary-400"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 row-end-2 overflow-visible fill-primary-400 transition-fill duration-500 ease-exponential [:where([data-current-route])_&]:fill-primary-50/0"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg></div><div class="grid grid-cols-0 transition-[grid-template-columns,margin-left,padding-right] duration-500 ease-exponential mly-auto [:where([data-expanded])_&]:ml-4 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:grid-cols-1 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pr-2"><span class="overflow-x-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-bold uppercase leading-none text-neutral-700 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-300 dark:desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-100 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:text-primary-400">Settings</span></div></a></li><hr class="rounded-full border border-neutral-500/25 m-2"><li class="log-out-button-container group/nav-item rounded-xl transition-[background-color] duration-500 ease-exponential active:bg-primary-100 data-[current-route]:pointer-events-none desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/50 desktop:active:bg-primary-100 dark:desktop:hover:bg-primary-50/25 dark:desktop:active:bg-primary-200/25 sticky bottom-0 before:absolute before:inset-x-0 before:-bottom-2 before:top-0 before:rounded-2xl before:bg-white/90 before:backdrop-blur-sm"><a class="grid grid-cols-[2rem_1fr] p-2" target="_self" rel="prefetch" href="#"><div class="grid size-8 place-items-center rounded-lg bg-primary-50 p-2 transition-[transform,background-color,box-shadow] duration-500 ease-exponential desktop:group-hover/nav-item:scale-105 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-md desktop:group-hover/nav-item:shadow-primary-600/15 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:bg-primary-400 group-active/nav-item:fill-primary-400 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:bg-primary-400"><svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 row-end-2 overflow-visible fill-primary-400 transition-fill duration-500 ease-exponential [:where([data-current-route])_&]:fill-primary-50/0 group-active/nav-item:fill-primary-50/0 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:fill-primary-50/0"><circle r='32' cx='32' cy='32' /></svg></div><div class="grid grid-cols-0 transition-[grid-template-columns,margin-left,padding-right] duration-500 ease-exponential mly-auto [:where([data-expanded])_&]:ml-4 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:grid-cols-1 [:where([data-expanded])_&]:pr-2"><span class="overflow-x-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-bold uppercase leading-none text-neutral-700 desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-300 dark:desktop:group-hover/nav-item:text-neutral-100 [:where([data-current-route])_&]:text-primary-400">Log Out</span></div></a></li></menu></nav></aside></body>



Let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful. Thank you!

Why sticky? Just position it absolute, and give the scroll container a padding-bottom (so that the last menu item will still be reachable.)

@CBroe Thanks for asking. I realize I didn't properly explain this in my question. I've just updated it.
